# Factorization of Polynomials over a Field: Question on Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Fraleigh's Abstract Algebra book this corollary is written and proven shortly after Gauss's lemma is introduced:

Corollary: If $f(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with $a_0 \neq 0$, and if $f(x)$ has a zero in $\mathbb{Q}$, then it has a zero $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $m$ must divide $a_0$.

Proof:
If $f(x)$ has a zero $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $f(x)$ has a linear factor $(x - a) \in \mathbb{Q}$, but then by Gauss's Lemma $f(x)$ also has a linear factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, so for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ we must have
$f(x) = (x - m)(x^{n-1} + \cdots - \frac{a_0}{m})$. Thus $a_0/m$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$, so $m$ divides $a_0$.

Now my question: From the Rational Root Thm since this is a monic polynomial, all the possible roots would have to be divisors of $a_0$, so the roots would always be in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$? Is this correct, if not can you show an example?

Comment: The *rational* roots are  integers, i.e. in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is it true then that this polynomial $f(x)$ cannot have roots in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ \ $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ (i.e. the elements of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ that are not integers)? If so, why is this theorem helpful?

Comment: I do not understand why you keep writing roots in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ and similar expressions. The result in about rational roots, and integer roots. The rational roots theorem and its relative proved above is useful, for one thing, because it gives us a procedure that is guaranteed to find all rational roots, if there are any.